# Как сделать построение маршрута между своими объектами?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Имеется файл data.json со списком объектов, в виде:

```
"point": {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 0,
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [50.621523, 36.578564] },
    "properties": {
      "balloonContent": "Корпус №1",
      "iconContent": "1",
      "clusterCaption": "Корпус №1",
      "hintContent": "Корпус №1",
      "balloonContentBody": "<img class='image' src='image/korp_1.jpg' /> <hr> <div class='mark'>Факультеты:</div><ul><li>Математики;</li><li>Естественнонаучного образования;</li></ul> <p><div class='mark'>Институт:</div> Инженерных технологий и естественных наук - инженерно-физическое направление;</p> <div class='mark'>Приемная комиссия</div> <hr> <div class='mark'>Телефон:</div>(4722) 30-18-80, 30-18-90, 30-18-79 <hr> <div class='mark'>Режим работы:</div>понедельник – пятница с 9.00 до 18.00 <br>перерыв с 13.00 до 14.00 ",
      "balloonContentHeader": "Корпус №1"
    }
  },
```

Возможно ли как то сделать так, что бы в стандартную форму построения маршрута добавлялись необходимые данные. что бы это выглядело как выпадающий список, в котором пользователь мог бы выбрать начальную и конечную точку из списка?
Может возможно как то кастомизировать метод из [примера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартную панель маршрутов поменять под эту задачу нельзя. Вам нужно делать собственную панель, в которой будет выбор точек начала и конца пути из вашего списка.

Comment: необходимо использовать control.RouteButton?

Comment: Либо делать реализацию из двух [ListBox](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.ListBox-docpage/?from=SO), либо реализуя полностью свой элемент управления - [вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO)

Comment: ну я так и предполагал что можно реализовать с помощью ListBox в своем элементе управления